# How to make WordPress editor (TinyMCE) preserve HTML formatting when switching between 'Visual' and 'Text'?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, tinymce

In WordPress editor (TinyMCE), whenever I switch between 'Visual' and 'Text' mode, all my HTML formatting gets removed. That includes tabs (indents) and line breaks. Sometimes, even elements and elements attributes are removed.

I searched a lot about this issue, which is actually a pretty common problem for many users, but after browsing 10 pages of Google, I got nothing but a plugin called **[Preserved HTML Editor Markup Plus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/preserved-html-editor-markup-plus/)**. The problem is this **[plugin conflicts with Yoast SEO plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/conflict-when-using-with-yoast-seo/)**.

Is there any thing I can do to preserve the HTML formatting, allowing both modes (Visual and Text) and not knowingly compromising other plugins?

Answer (score 1):

You should try TinyMCE Advanced Plugin.

[TinyMCE Advanced](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/) have set to Stop removing the `<p> and <br /> tags` when saving and show them in the HTML editor.

Try it after removing another editor plugin which you have installed to prevent conflict with other.

The second option is [Raw HTML](https://wordpress.org/plugins/raw-html/) plugin. It has also a good feature to prevent HTML formatting. You can use `[raw]` shortcode like  `[raw] YOUR HTML [/raw]` to prevent HTML formating.

You can try this both plugin once. Hope one of from these option work for you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wordperss has **wp_kses** function that only allow certain html tag in post content.

If you want to certain html tag / attributes allowed in your post content , you need to remove kses filter ( **kses_remove_filter** ) functions added in your theme / plugin.

**Reference**

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/kses_remove_filters/

Comment: Thank you. It helps, but it does not exactly solve my problem, because indentation is still getting ripped.